# CSS transition fill property works only one way

Tags: css

I have a container that holds a SVG. On click, the SVG changes with some other SVG.

The first SVG has

```
.filled {
  fill: blue;
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
}
```

The other one is actually the same image but without fill.

```
.unfilled {
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
}
```

When transitioning from the unfilled to the filled SVG, the animation works. But it does not work the other way around. (the transition is instant)

Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong?

Comment: It would be better if you provide a working example of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ease-in` to `ease-in-out`.

More info on transitions is available here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score -1):

I just changed the class using jQuery and it seems to work.

JS

```
$('#changeme').on("click", function() {
    $("#mySvg").attr('class', 'unfilled');
});
```

HTML

```
 <svg width="100" height="100">
       <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" id="mySvg" class="filled" />
  </svg>
  <button id="changeme">Change me</button>
```

Comment: A constructive criticism would be better if someone is going to down vote so  I can learn from it